# Why this code doesn't work? Selection sort Python

Tags: arrays, sorting

I can't get why this code doesn't work. It outputs IndexError: pop index out of range. It's a book example, not my own code.

```
def  find_smallest(arr):
    #store the smallest value 
    smallest = arr[0]
    #store the index of the smallest value
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest

#sorts an array
def selection_sort(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        #find the smallest element in the array, and adds it to the new array
        smallest = find_smallest(arr)
        new_arr.append(arr.pop(smallest))
    return new_arr

print(selection_sort([5, 3, 6, 2, 10]))
```

Comment: pop takes in index, not a value.... 
find_smallest() should `return smallest_index`

Comment: Thanks, I have already read about pop method and solve the problem. In the end, It's all about print mistake in the book on my native language)